# Rewrite which was working with Apache 2.2 doesn't work on Apache 2.4

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect-loop

I have to migrate my company website to a new Cloud VPS and I'm getting a redirect loop because of the rewrite which was just working fine on old server. It works for some page like Login which was dedicated to be only work with `https`.

I read a lot already about this and I tried, nothing helped me.

Here is the original rewrite from `.htaccess` file

```
    php_flag session.auto_start Off

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I found some similar question on this Stack Overflow also - I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: What is the sense of the `NC` flag if you do not match against specific characters?

Comment: Oh! I was just re-posting the original .htaccess file. Actually, this file was written by another person long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorten your rule patterns to just `^` and change their flags to just `END`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a bunch! I just got out from the redirect loop. The fault is me not reading the `Apache` documents properly. Now, `index` page is up and running. Problem is no `js`and `css` are being loaded but that's another problem. Your answer really helped.